# Allow hitting tab to go to Vote to Close button in Vote to Close dialog

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, close-dialog

Right now, if you Vote to Close a question, and select one of the reasons (say Not Constructive) you need to manually press the `Vote to Close` button by taking your mouse to it and pressing.

Could we have it tabbed instead? So that I can select the option, and hit `tab` followed by `enter`.

Right now, hitting tab takes me to the search bar, and then the links on the SO page below the dialog in the expected order.

EDIT: Going through the flag review que, I've also noticed the same behavior when flagging as `Invalid Flag` or `Not an Answer` etc. However, hitting tab works perfectly when adding a custom message using the `Other` option. I'm asking for the same behavior to be applied to the options without a text box as well.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? It's possible. But if there's anything in the tab navigation "path" in between, such as a link in a flag reason's description, you will need to <kbd>tab</kbd> past those first.